# Connect a PC to PSTN network

Tags: voip

I have a land-line phone through my ISP. I use it to call land-line phones free of charge like phones in Europe etc. what I want to do is that I want to use this service from any PC so I can call any land-line phone.

I'm a newbie in this but what I understood so far is that I need to install some kind of VOIP server on PC and connect that server to my home router. The VOIP server will provide me with user name/password that I can use on a VOIP client app on any PC. So that I can authenticate myself from anywhere in VOIP server and call for free. I hope I've explained clearly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk is the go to open source PBX.  Digium makes PCI cards that work with Asterisk and have FXO ports for connecting a PC to the PSTN/POTS.  Your standard home router possibly isn't going to handle NAT traversal for VoIP very well so if you can get the client to ring (SIP) but don't hear any voice (RTSP) this is likely why.

Comment: @Aaron Copley - yes, this is certainly off topic, but please keep text in answers to *actual* answers.

Comment: Yep, you're right I should have left that seperately as a comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Who is your service provider?  I assume what you're paying for is VOIP already, so perhaps all you have to do is get SIP credentials from your service provider and use their VOIP server.